# How to get modelview metadata in Autodesk Forge SFV2 format?

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer, autodesk-model-derivative

I would like to get modelview metadata with the new format that SVF2 uses. I need it to get assigned dbIDs to the list of elements name that I have, to preprocess data.

I've uploaded and translated .nwd file in SVF2 format, where dbIDs are assigned in "Breadth First Search" way. However, when I get modelview metadata, it returns exactly the same modelview metadata as SVF format, where dbIDs are assigned in "Depth First Search" way.

BTW, I use https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/model-derivative/v2/reference/http/urn-metadata-guid-GET/ to get the metadata.

In the image below, the left side shows what I get (SVF format) from the the model translated in SVF2 format, and the right side show what I expect, which is the format that SVF2 uses.

[dbIDs assignment format for SVF2, what I get vs what I expect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wWhai.jpg)

Please let me know, how can I get the right modelview metadata for SVF2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **SVF2** format is still being rolled out (currently in public beta), and unfortunately the Model Derivative metadata endpoint currently only provides **SVF1** metadata.

At the moment, the only way to get the corresponding metadata for an SVF2 model is through the Forge Viewer APIs. For example, when you load your SVF2 model into the viewer, select one of the elements, and display the *Properties* panel, you should see the correct metadata there.

Comment: With that said, I will pass this information to the engineering team to make sure that the MD endpoints can be used with SVF2 as well.

Comment: Btw. here's a temporary workaround until the SVF1/SVF2 dbid mapping is provided by the Model Derivative service: https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/temporary-workaround-mapping-between-svf1-and-svf2-ids.